# 404 Not Found While Passing id to another Controller - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know why I'm getting 404 not found error when I'm trying to pass an id to another controller.

here's my index.blade.php

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{{ route('receiving_details', 
['id'=>$r_main->id])}}" title="Show Received Data"><i class="fa fa-arrow 
right"</i></a>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('receiving_details/{$id}',[
"uses" => 'ReceivingDetailsController@index',
"as" => 'receiving_details' 
]);
```

ReceivingDetailsController.blade.php(This is where I want to pass id from view.blade.php)

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class ReceivingDetailsController extends Controller
  {
    public function index($id){
       echo $id;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Remove `$` from your get request `receiving_details/{id}` and try.

Comment: It works now. thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `$` from your get request.

```
Route::get('receiving_details/{id}',[
"uses" => 'ReceivingDetailsController@index',
"as" => 'receiving_details' 
]);
```

Comment: omg I didn't notice that haha it works now. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

In your href please have this little adjustment

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href="{{ route('receiving_details', $r_main->id)}}" title="Show Received Data"><i class="fa fa-arrow right"</i></a>
```